# Set PDO connection without password

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database in Altervista. I want to use a PDO connection without password. Can I do it?

It's right?

```
 $col = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_edoardopavan';
 try {
    $conn = new PDO($col , $username);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 }
 catch(PDOException $e)
 {
     die("OOPs something went wrong");
 }
```

Comment: Sure it'll work - but why? And why ask the question since this is so easily testable?

Comment: `$password` is an optional param http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php  If the connection allows for a blank password with that username, it will work fine.